# Zend Framework, Sessions, and HttpOnly

Tags: php, zend-framework, session, httponly

I want to make my session cookie `HttpOnly`.  Based on [this article](http://docs.cellblue.nl/2010/04/21/using-httponly-cookies-in-zend-framework-using-zend_session/), I added this to my `application.ini`:

```
resources.session.cookie_httponly = true
```

Unfortunately, when I look at the session cookie in [Firecookie](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6683/), it is *not* marked as `HttpOnly` as I have specified.  What step am I missing?

[image]

Comment: "when I look at the session cookie in Firecookie, it is not marked as HttpOnly" --- how exactly cookie should be marked? What did you expect to see there?

Comment: `HttpOnly` **is** a step to protect from XSS: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/protecting-your-cookies-httponly.html

Comment: @Sonny: it is a step to protect against cookies hijacking, not xss. XSS is just a way to send the cookies, and `HttpOnly` is the option that does not allow you to read cookies from js. So it protects cookie from being readed in js. There is no connection between XSS and `HttpOnly`.

Comment: FTA: "HttpOnly cookies are a great idea, and properly implemented, make huge classes of common XSS attacks much harder to pull off."

Comment: @Sonny: omg... `HttpOnly` protects from cookie being read. Without this option your site is not more XSS vulnerable.

Comment: Why are you being argumentative rather than helpful?  This is not the only step I take for security, I just want to use all available tools.

Comment: @Sonny: I just corrected you, because your phrase "I want to make my session cookie HttpOnly to reduce XSS vulnerabilities" is just wrong and I do care of future not-experienced readers who will follow your words.

Comment: Well, on-topic now: Have you looked at the response headers?

Comment: When I look at the Response and Request headers in Firebug, I can see a Set-Cookie line that specifies HttpOnly, but this is for a cookie other than my session cookie. Firecookie shows an HttpOnly column, and the cookie I am specifying HttpOnly is marked as such, but my session is not.  I don't know where else to look.

Comment: if it helps, removing the PHP session cookie and starting the session again is the first test for testing. Mine worked with only the ini setting

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try at bootstrap to do `Zend_Session::setOptions(array('cookie_httponly' => true));` ( somewhere before the session is first initialized ) tough it should work with the app.ini file too .

Comment: This works. I wish I could figure out why it's not reading from `application.ini`.

Comment: will have a look and let you know if i find something .

Comment: Use `Zend_Session::setOptions(array('cookie_httponly' => true));` instead of `Zend_Session::setOptions(array('cookie_httponly', true))`;

Answer (score 7):

Add this to your application.ini file.

```
phpSettings.session.cookie_httponly = true
```

Answer (score 1):

For this to be 100% safe.

The server should not allow the option http trace.
The http option trace reports the session id.
If a attacker can inject a java applet, flash or javascript with ajax the attacker can also steal cookies even with the httponly flag set...